# Google Analytics reporting API returns only one row

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I followed the php [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php) so I have that code:

```
  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

  // Create the Metrics object.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
  $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
```

But that prints only a total, not the detail. I searched in [that guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics) but from what I understand it should return all sessions then I don't unerstand.

Comment: did you check the `printResults($response);` method?

Comment: yes sure, it list the result. I checked the result object and ther's only one row.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you missed `printResults($report)` method here, It's already implement on the official documentation site.

```
$response = getReport($analytics);
printResults($response); // this method will iterate the result set
```

**Full Method**

```
/**
 * Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 *
 * @param An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 */
function printResults($reports) {
  for ( $reportIndex = 0; $reportIndex < count( $reports ); $reportIndex++ ) {
    $report = $reports[ $reportIndex ];
    $header = $report->getColumnHeader();
    $dimensionHeaders = $header->getDimensions();
    $metricHeaders = $header->getMetricHeader()->getMetricHeaderEntries();
    $rows = $report->getData()->getRows();

    for ( $rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex < count($rows); $rowIndex++) {
      $row = $rows[ $rowIndex ];
      $dimensions = $row->getDimensions();
      $metrics = $row->getMetrics();
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($dimensionHeaders) && $i < count($dimensions); $i++) {
        print($dimensionHeaders[$i] . ": " . $dimensions[$i] . "\n");
      }

      for ($j = 0; $j < count($metrics); $j++) {
        $values = $metrics[$j]->getValues();
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($values); $k++) {
          $entry = $metricHeaders[$k];
          print($entry->getName() . ": " . $values[$k] . "\n");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No I took the full code but that displays only the total... the problem is that the $result contains only one row

Answer (score 0):

See if that helps. (method using service account):

How to create the service account: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php?hl=pt-br

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json'; // <-- Service account credentials

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
$client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
$token = $client->getAccessToken();
$accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
$items = $accounts->getItems();
$total_contas = count($items);
if($total_contas > 0){
$firstAccountId = $items[0]->getId();
$properties = $analytics->management_webproperties->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);
$items = $properties->getItems();
$firstPropertyId = $items[0]->getId();
$profiles = $analytics->management_profiles->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstPropertyId);
$items = $profiles->getItems();
}
?>

<canvas id="grafico-analytics" height="300px"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
}(window,document,'script'));
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
'serverAuth': {
'access_token': '<?php echo $token['access_token']; ?>' // Do not modify
}
});

Promise.all([query({
'ids': 'ga:<?php echo $items[0]->id; ?>', // Do not modify
'dimensions': 'ga:date,ga:nthDay',
'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
'start-date': '2018-12-01',
'end-date': '2018-12-12'
})]).then(function(results) {
var data1 = results[0].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
var labels = results[0].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[0]; });

labels = labels.map(function(label) {
return moment(label, 'YYYYMMDD').format('d MMM D YYYY');
});

var ctx = document.getElementById("grafico-analytics").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: {
labels : labels,
datasets : [
{
label: 'PageViews',
backgroundColor: 'rgba(51,0,204, 0.2)',
borderColor: 'rgba(51,0,204, 1)',
borderWidth: 3,
data : data1
}
]
},
options:{
responsive: false,
scales:{
xAxes: [{
display: false,
}],
}
}
});
});
function query(params) {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
var data = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({query: params});
data.once('success', function(response) { resolve(response); })
.once('error', function(response) { reject(response); })
.execute();
});
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: I could not do with PHP, it was what I wanted, but I could not, and since I was already delaying the delivery of the project I decided to do in Javascript

Comment: I followed the presentation on the link (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php) but only returned the full amount as well.

Comment: Is it a bug in the php api ?

Comment: Should be, as I did not modify the code, but only returned the total hits